# I get 'Module: command not found' when compiling program

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, compilation, macos-sierra

I'm using macOS sierra and when running a compile script am getting the error:

Module: Command not found

It is my impression that macOS doesn't have module. Is there any way I can work around this / get module?

Kind Regards,

Neil

Comment: Please provide more information, like the script that produced this error.

Comment: Sorry I was being dumb.... I don't need to load the module in macOS, but I do on my linux server at work .